# Как воспроизвести видео через стрим и буферить?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, потоки-данных

У меня есть такой код, я тут выкачиваю mp4 и воспроизвожу через blob протокол. Сейчас все хорошо работает, но работает хорошо из-за того, что видео 20 секунд идет, но если взять 25 минутное видео в 1040 формате, ждать его скачивание очень долго. Я хочу воспроизвести его частями, чтобы сразу можно было смотреть. Можете пожалуйста поправить мой код? Я читал и пробовал сделать это самостоятельно, но ничего не получается у меня :(

```
function App() {
  const [src, setSrc] = React.useState('')
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchVideo = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('//assets.mixkit.co/videos/preview/mixkit-white-cat-lying-among-the-grasses-seen-up-close-22732-large.mp4', { responseType: 'blob' })

        console.log(response)

        setSrc(URL.createObjectURL(response.data))
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    };

    fetchVideo()
  }, [])

  console.log(src)

  return (<video src={src} controls />);
}
```

Comment: Ну если вы хотите стрим, то и пишите `responseType: 'stream'` и работайте потом со стримом.

Comment: Я же написал, что я пытался работать, у меня не получается;(

Comment: а почему не хочешь сразу в src урл подставить?

Comment: По многим причинам